# Node.js - Why mongoose not saving data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've the following code:

```
const Box = mongoose.model("box", {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        mac: String
    });

    Box.findOne({ mac: "MACADDRESS" }, function (err, data) {

        data._doc.name = "box 2";

        data.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

        });

    });
```

I can't identify why the document is not saving. Anyone can help me?

Comment: can you try data.name = "box 2"; instead of data._doc.name = "box 2";
 ? see the last section here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Comment: I tried to do this, but not update as well =/

Comment: try with Box.save(data,function(){})

Comment: nothing happens as well =/

Comment: oh sorry your key name is "mac" and you are updating name so it will be like data.mac = "box 2";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model definition has `mac` in the attribute so it may go like this

```
Box.findOne({ mac: "MACADDRESS" }, function (err, data) {
    data.mac = "box 2";
    data.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```